# How to recover 15g gold from 50 gallons of 30% Acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Someone mistakenly poured a solution containing $15\mathrm{g}$ of gold into a nearly full waste drum that is around $30$% $\ce{HCl}$ with a little nitric acid in there as well.

Is there a safe way of separating the acid from the gold via distillation?

Comment: You can more or less safely use distillation to concentrate the solution. Likely, some amount of chlorine and nitrogen oxides will be produced, but fume hood should be enough to deal with it. Once the solution would be concentrated to amount of several tens of ml, some chemical method to precipitate gold may be used, say, neutralizing the solution followed with reduction by $\ce{Zn}$ followed by washing the precipitate with $\ce{HCl}$

Comment: At a rate of USD 1200/oz, it's a lot of work to recover USD 600 worth of gold.

Answer (score 2):

You could distill the waste easily enough, but the distillation gases will be rather nasty. You will also need a condenser to cool everything down again or the environmental penalties (and corrosion damage to the exhaust system) will be a lot more than the gold value.

Once you have the waste boiled down (literally) into a small flask you could use any of the known gold-extraction methods to get it out in elemental form.

At current market prices you have about US$580 of gold in the drum. No idea how much you will spend in fuel and cooling water to recover it but it will be a substantial percentage. Why don't you just tell "Someone" that they can either pay for the gold they dumped or mind the still themselves over the weekend (and pay for the propane). This will also encourage others to pay more attention to what is in the beaker.

Comment: Before giving "someone" the choice, consider whether you'd *really* trust the same person who dumped the gold in the waste drum in the first place to a) choose wisely, or b) carry out the distillation safely and without further material damage.

Comment: Thankyou for ideas. I plan to use a glass condenser to avoid corrosion. I'm not sure whether it will be liquid or air cooled. I know the liquid ones are more popular in general, but it would be really nice to use long thin glass tubes that are air cooled. That is another question entirely though.

Comment: Also, to answer your question: I have to build the still first.